# Type Error - stem() missing 1 required positional argument : 'word'

Tags: python, porter-stemmer, stem

I am working on a script to extract relevant tags from the text file which i converted from a URL. One part of the script is giving me error when i apply stemmer, the code is as below

```
def __call__(self, tag):
    '''
    @param tag: the tag to be stemmed

    @returns: the stemmed tag
    '''

    string = self.preprocess(tag.string)
    tag.stem = self.stemmer.stem(string)
    return tag
```

the error is  as below

```
Type Error - stem() missing 1 required positional argument : 'word'
```

the line causing the error is

```
tag.stem = self.stemmer.stem(string)
```

I am using Python, if anyone can help me to modify the code to get rid of the error please.

Comment: what is `self.stemmer.stem`'s definition?

Comment: def __init__(self, string, stem=None, rating=1.0, proper=False,
                 terminal=False):

            
        self.string  = string
        self.stem = stem or string

Comment: Please edit the original post and add that, it doesn't belong in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't instantiate `self.stemmer`,ie

```
class stemmer(object):
    def stem(self, word):
        print('stem')

obj = stemmer 
obj.stem("word")
```

this will cause same error,beacause `Class` won't pass `self` argument to method,so you need instantiate the stemmer

```
obj = stemmer()
obj.stem("word")
```

Comment: Right.  `stemmer.stem()` invokes `stem` as a *class method* so there's no object to implicitly pass as the first (`self`) parameter.  `stemmer().stem()` invokes it as an *object method* and implicitly passes the object (created by `stemmer()`) as the first argument (`self`).

Answer (score 1):

While initializing `ps=PorterStemmer()`, kindly check the braces are correct.

Comment: I think you mean "parentheses" (`()`) not "braces" (`[]` or `{}`).

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.